# Summing Only Visible Rows in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, aggregate, visibility, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to sum only the visible rows for a report and I know the format is:

```
=Sum( iif( <use the condition of the Visibility.Hidden expression>, 0, Fields!A.Value))
```

In my report, I've set row visbility to:

```
=IIF(CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)=1 Or CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)= 2,True,False)
```

Not exactly sure what I'm missing, but when I use this as an expression:

```
=Sum(IIF(CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)=1 Or CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)= 2,True,False),0,Fields!EM_ET.Value)
```

I get this following error: Value expression for textrun'FTD1.Paragraph[0].TextRuns[0]' has a scope argument that is not valid for aggregate function.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving the `True/False` as output to the `SUM()` from your expression.You need to change your expression as,

```
=Sum(IIF(CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value) = 1 Or CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)= 2,0,Fields!EM_ET.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks coder of code.
I am getting some error message if i am using '0', so i replaced with nothing it's working. I thought it would be helpful.

```
=SUM(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!value1.Value) OR ISNOTHING(Fields!value2.Value),NOTHING,Fields!value1.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues. I know this question has a marked answer, however it isn't entirely correct.

The following contains the code from the "marked correct" answer:

```
=Sum(IIF(CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value) = 1 Or CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value) = 2,0,Fields!EM_ET.Value))
```

The following snipit of code contains the code from above, with a slight tweak:

```
=Sum(IIF(CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value) = 1 Or CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value) = 2,NOTHING,Fields!EM_ET.Value))
```

By changing the "0" to "NOTHING" this will resolve any lingering issues with your formula. The formula I was having issues with was returning "#Error" in the cell that was supposed to return the sum of the visible cells in the column within the row group.

My formula originally looked like this:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!VCBitType.Value) <> 0 OR (Parameters!Details.Value = "Detail"), Sum(IIF((Fields!VCBitType.Value = 0) and (Parameters!Details.Value = "Dangerous"),0,Fields!VC.Value)), "")
```

I altered my formula after seeing Hari's comment above:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!VCBitType.Value) <> 0 OR (Parameters!Details.Value = "Detail"), SUM(IIF((Fields!VCBitType.Value = 0) and (Parameters!Details.Value = "Dangerous"),NOTHING, Fields!VC.Value)), "")
```

I wanted to set the cells value to "" (empty) rather than hide the cell entirely or set that cell's value to "0" in my report (due to the fact that not displaying the cell entirely made the report look really funky). Because I did this, using a "0" in my formula conflicted with the value of the cell which was "" (empty), causing the formula to break. The only change I made was to alter "0" to "Nothing", this resolved the issue I was having with the cell's formula.